# I need to delete Duplicate data From a database Programmability in MS access

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net

I have a Database with a Table Security and 2 Fields username and password which contains several Duplicate data I want to delete Duplicate in C#.net what is the SQL statement that I would use.The Duplicate username and password come during the update of the database file from another file. Or how to I copy only the records that dose not exist in the databata base file. I need to do that IN CSharp.net here it the part of the code where i want to do the removal of the data.
PLEASE HELP

```
        private void ReadUFbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    //new data in desktop so it comes as Source so main becomes as backup
            // backup is main so here is mail pis in opened 
            string targetPath = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Prashant\";
            string constr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\PIS.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=Prashant;";
            Con = new OleDbConnection(@constr);
            Con.Open();
            Com = new OleDbCommand();
            Com.Connection = Con;

              try
              {
                  if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
                  {
                      DialogResult X = MessageBox.Show("The Direcory / 5File Dose not exits", "PIS System");
                  }
                  else
                  {   
                      //backup open           
                      if (Con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                          Con.Open();
                          //target //main //backup              //source from data //desktop
                          //backup                                           // main data 
                      string selQuery = "INSERT INTO Security SELECT DISTINCT * FROM [MS Access;DATABASE=c:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Prashant\\PIS.mdb;PWD=Prashant;].[Security]";

                          Com.CommandText = selQuery;
                          Com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                          Com.Connection = Con;

                          MessageBox.Show("File Updated");
                          Com.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Security  ";

                          int result = Com.ExecuteNonQuery();

                   }                     
                }
                catch(Exception ex) 
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
           }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Executing something like this should remove duplicate records in MS-Access

```
delete from Security 
where id not in
(select min(id) from Security T2
 where T2.username=Security.username and T2.password=Security.password)
```